# retrieve info from post and place in a formated xml in php

Tags: php, xml, post

I have a post and i need to retrive some data and place it in an xml.

My xml formate is like this

```
<maintag>

      <item>
          postinfo (variable = value)
      <item>

<maintag>
```

I´m getting only the variable = value. I don´t know how to create an item tag for very post and place it under the maintag.

Here is my php code.

```
<?php
header ('Location: http:thanskforpostingpage.html');
$handle = fopen("postedinfo.xml", "a");
foreach($_POST as $variable => $value) {
  fwrite($handle, $variable);
  fwrite($handle, "=");
  fwrite($handle, $value);
  fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
}
fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
fclose($handle);
exit;
?>
```

after posting the xml should look like

```
<maintag>



      <item>
          postinfo (variable = value)
      <item>

      <item>
          postinfo (variable = value)
      <item>

<maintag>
```

note that it has been aded a new item tag but the maintag stills the same
. so every post it will ad some new info to the xml

Comment: And your question with that is? Where do you hit the roadblock?

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually output the xml tags as well...

```
$handle = fopen(...);
fwrite($handle, "<maintag>");
foreach(...) {
    fwrite($handle, "<item>");
    fwrite($handle, $variable);
    ...
    fwrite($handle, "</item">);
}
fwrite($handle, "</maintag>");
fclose($handle);
```

PHP is not smart and won't see that you've opened a `.xml` file for writing, and suddenly/magically know you need to include the various tags... That's YOUR job.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I need to add items inside the maintag, this way I´m not creating a new maintag? Sorry the question I´m very dumb in php. should tell the php to search for the maintag and write under it using as you said the fwrite <item>

Comment: you have an existing xml file you need to add more `<item>` tags to? The use [DOM](http://php.net/dom) to manipulate the file properly. If you were building a new xml from scratch, then my code above would be the way to go.